# Magento 2.3.1 : Validation exception in developer mode

Tags: magento2, exception, developer-mode

When switching from production mode to developer in Magento 2.3.1 the enclosed exception occurs. I have tried to find a solution for 2 days. From what I've read this is probably caused by a .xml file that needs to be changed but I can't find any hint as to what .xml file to look at.[image: Validation exception]

Comment: I would search for issue in some custom layout xml's. Problem could be also in one of the cms pages field "Layout Update XML"

Answer (score 0):

Someone suggested this approach in another post

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/274918/70343

Perhaps it will work for you